# How to read workspace file content with P4JsApi?

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to do some customizations for P4V using [P4JsApi](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4jsapi/01_p4jsapi.html) and I can not figure out how to read workspace file content, any suggestions ?

(P4JsApi supports "p4 print" command but it seems to be only for depot files; "p4 print" + "p4 diff" is a way to get workspace file content, but it is complex and seems not suitable for new(add) file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this now with P4JsApi, but the pending P4V release may contain a command to print workspace file content just as "p4 print".